# How to create the Comparable interface in C++ and pass an array of comparables?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Runnable code sample: [run this code here online](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/BixhJyO)

I do know the correct full example should be use template classes, but for the sake of simplicity I would like to see a naive implementation without templates.

I also know that virtual operator overload of the < or > operator would be more appropriate in C++ instead of the polymorphic compareTo() method signature.

I also know about arrays are not covariant, neither contravariant, still I would like to see how this example should work in C++, I do not want to use STL template type like vector

I define the abstract class (interface):

```
class Comparable {
    public:
    virtual int compareTo(Comparable *) = 0;
};
```

I have a base class, independently of the concept of "Comparable"

```
class Shape {
protected:    
    int width, height;
public:
    Shape(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    {
        width = a;
        height = b;
    }
    virtual int area() = 0;
};
```

I defined a Shape descendant Rectangle, *which would like to be a Comparable:*

```
class Rectangle : public Shape, public Comparable {

public:
    Rectangle(int a = 0, int b = 0) : Shape(a, b) {}

    virtual int compareTo(Comparable * other){
        return height - dynamic_cast<Rectangle *>(other)->height;
    } 

    int area()
    {
        return (width * height);
    }
};
```

**Test method and main program:
See the comments in the test(...) method.
What am I missing here?**

```
void test(Comparable* items[]){
    // tests polymorphic behavior. For example this would be a sort algorithm, 
    // which gets and array of comparables (array of pointers to Comparable)
    
    int result = items[0]->compareTo(items[1]);

    // result is 42 here, despite it is the meaning of life, is not appropriate. It is the area() method return value of items[0], instead of compareTo()
    // Debugging justifies, that not the compareTo method is called on the items[0] instance
    // instead the area() method... something is wrong with the cast... and not the correct method address used from the vtable ...
}

int main()
{
    Rectangle a(3,14), b(3,11);
    Rectangle* rectangles[2];
    rectangles[0] = &a;
    rectangles[1] = &b;

    // This is not good, but what would be the correct?
    test((Comparable **)rectangles);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `//This is not good, but what would be the correct?` This problem also has _almost nothing_ to do with comparableTo, so I would recommend removing that from the question

Comment: Also your `Comparable` interface is _extremely_ dangerous without templates, as evidenced by the `dynamic_cast<Rectangle *>(other)->height`, which will crash with undefined behavior, if provided anything but a Rectangle. At least prefer `dynamic_cast<Rectangle&>(*other).height` which will throw an exception instead.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast comments. 1) Agree with the first comment, title is bad. 2) I do not understand why templates unevitable 3) The cast inside the compareTo is dangerous, **but this is an other topic**. Why the area() method is called, instead of compareTo?

Comment: A `Rectangle` is a `Comparable` a `Rectangle*` is not a `Comparable*`. Having to brute force with a C-style cast is usually the first warning that things are about to go wrong.

Comment: @idclev463035818, fair enough comment. My motivation is to see demonstrate polymorhic behavoiur in C++, and understand C++ features, step by step. Polymorphic behaviour is independent of the template C++ feature. I do no understand what is so catastrophic wrong in my example, so the area method is called instead of compareTo

Comment: To ease testing, I've added an online C++ fiddle link, so just click and run, and modify the code

Comment: @g.pickardou: Until you get into _really really_ advanced concepts, consider all explicit C-style casts, `reinterpret_cast`, and `const_cast` to be bugs. Also consider `dynamic_cast` with extreme suspicion. `(Comparable **)` is what went wrong. `rectangles` does NOT point at an array of `Comparable*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(Comparable **)rectangles`
You're getting strange results because this cast is an invalid reinterpret_cast. This invalid cast is causing undefined behavior. In your case, the undefined behavior represented itself as calling a different method, rather than deleting your files, so you were lucky.

C++ arrays are not covariant nor contravariant, specifically *because* casts like this won't work. Instead, you have to either use templates, or  make a copy:

```
int main()
{
    Rectangle a(3,14), b(3,11);
    Rectangle* rectangles[2];
    rectangles[0] = &a;
    rectangles[1] = &b;

    //See these changes here
    Comparable* comparables[2];
    comparables[0] = static_cast<Comparable*>(rectangles[0]);
    comparables[1] = static_cast<Comparable*>(rectangles[1]);
    test(comparables);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Under the covers, it probably failed because the normal implementations are like this:

```
ComparableVirtualTable class layout:
    int(*compareTo)(Comparable*);

Comparable class layout: 
    ComparableVirtualTable* comparableVirtualTable;

ShapeVirtualTable class layout: 
    int (*area)();

Shape class layout: 
    ShapeVirtualTable* shapeVirtualTable;
    int width;
    int height;

Rectangle class layout:
    //Contains Shape members
    ShapeVirtualTable* shapeVirtualTable;
    int width;
    int height;
    //followed by Comparable members
    ComparableVirtualTable* comparableVirtualTable;
```

Notably: The Shape members and virtual table come before the Comparable virtual table.  So the `static_cast<Comparable>*(rectangles[...])` will actually return a pointer to the start of the `Comparable` part of the `Rectangle`, and does *NOT* point at the start of the `Rectangle` itself. This is why your `(Comparable **)` failed, is that it treated the array of `Rectangle` pointers as an array of `Comparable` pointers, but the pointers *were not pointing at `Comparable` data members!*

---

Sidenote: All classes with `virtual` methods should also have a `virtual` destructor defined: `virtual ~Comparable(){}`

Comment: Many thanks. Having the assignment of each element of the array each Rectangle * implicitly casted to Comparable *, if I understand correctly. Is there any way to not copy (so duplicate) the the array and still make this work? My original idea was the Comparable& array[] as the formal parameter of the test(Comparable& items[])  but that is not supported.

Comment: Yes, the implicit cast is a safe static cast. I've replaced it with an explicit C++ cast to make this clear.  One can also use `Comparable* comparables[] = {&a, &b};` to copy/duplicate the array in a more concise syntax, but it's fundamentally the same thing occurring.  There is no way to avoid the copy, as you start with a `Rectangle*[2]`, and the function takes a `Comparable*[2]`, and those _arrays_ are completely unrelated to each other, and in fact, the pointers in them point to different memory addresses, which is why your `(Comparable **)` cast failed.

Answer (score 0):

An additional layer of abstraction solves all sorts of problems.

- Create a container class based on a private array of Comparables.
- Implement `push_back` or some other convenience functions for putting in Comparable object pointers.
- Implement a `get(int index)` member function.
- Implement a `test` member function.